# element.setAttibute() method how to make it work in I.E?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, setattribute

I am setting the style attribute of a text via js **element.setAttribute()** method with name=style and value="my modifications to the style of text"

it is working well in browsers other than IE ..

In order to make it possible ,what should i do ?

for your information i m modifying these attributes -- text-align,text-decoration,font-style,font-weight,font-size....

I will be happy if someone guides me 
thank you..

Comment: [This question is possibly the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691927/javascript-setattribute-alternative). You might get ideas from there.

Comment: All the "attributes" you listed are CSS properties and should be set on `element.style`. Something like `element.setAttribute('text-align')` won't work.

Comment: @Felix he was trying with `element.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: center;')` but IE doesn't treat `style` as attribute unlike other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way for IE which "preserve" the ordinary syntax of CSS is `cssText` property:

```
element.style.cssText = "text-align: center; text-decoration: underline; font-size: 120%;";
```

Official documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533698(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid `setAttribute`. It does nothing that can't be done though other methods.

```
element.style.textAlign = 'left';
```

for example.

That said, you are almost certainly better off predefining your styles and then causing them to be applied with:

```
element.className += 'someClass';
```

… or a library that implements `addClass` and `removeClass` methods.